# jquery ajax sending same request through a loop?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Is it possible to send the same POST request through ajax using .post() in a loop?

let's say i have array, and for each element in it I would want to send a post request such as update, delete from a database.

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you cn do something like this,

```
yourArrayObj.forEach(function(singleEle){
   $ajax.post('/your_url',requestData,successCallback,errorCallback);
});
```

Comment: thank you v31 this is simpler than the mess I was making. One last question, is the successCallback going to be load as many times as elements there is an array. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Unfortunately it will get loaded everytime but you can have a condition inside it to avoid for some cases. Do remember to mark this as your answer